# Does $f=g$ as the maps on the underlying topological spaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f,g:X\to Y$ be two morphisms of schemes, if $U$ is a dense open set of $X$, and $f|_U=g|_U$ as morphisms of schemes, does $f=g$ as the maps on the underlying topological spaces?

Comment: Consider two inclusions of a line into the line with two origins and $U$ the line without origin

Comment: You probably want separated hypotheses.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Are $f,g$ separated morphisms?

Comment: @Borntobeproud No, I'm saying that if you assume that are morphisms over some base $S$ over which $Y$ and $Z$ are separated, and $Y$ is a reduced scheme then this is true (even that $f=g$ as scheme maps). For example, see 10.2.2 of this: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf

Comment: In the purely topological case you require $Y$ to be Hausdorff, so that the set $\{x\in X, f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed. Schemes are rarely Hausdorff, but the analogous condition for schemes is separated.